# PopupWindow and setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: android

Calling `setBackgroundDrawable` before showing the PopupWindow works fine. But when I call it after showing the PopupWindow it has no effect.

Is there a particular way I need to set the background after the PopupWindow is shown?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I can set the background of the main layout view of the PopupWindow...

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `invalidate()` after calling `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: PopupWindow has no ``invalidate`` method... :-)